# Grafana Loki communication error 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: docker-compose, grafana, podman, grafana-loki, promtail

I spent three days to find out where the problem is but without any success. The scenario is quite simple, I tried to deploy stack with grafana, grafana loki, promtail, kafka. I tried it with this docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

networks:
  kafka-net:
    name: kafka-net
    driver: bridge

services:
  kafka_broker:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    container_name: kafka_broker
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    ports:
      - '9094:9094'
    environment:
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
        KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT: 'yes'
        KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES: broker,controller
        KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
        KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: CLIENT://:29092,CONTROLLER://:9093,EXTERNAL://:9094
        KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
        KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: CLIENT
        KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: CLIENT://kafka_broker:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9094
        KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: 1@127.0.0.1:9093
        KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'false'
        KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: 'yes'

  kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    container_name: kafka-ui
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: "local"
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: "kafka_broker:29092"
    depends_on:
      - "kafka_broker"

  loki:
    image: grafana/loki:latest
    container_name: loki
    ports:
      - "3100:3100"
    command: -config.file=/etc/loki/local-config.yaml
    networks:
      - kafka-net

  promtail:
    image: grafana/promtail:latest
    container_name: promtail
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/containers:/var/lib/docker/containers
      - /var/workspace/promtail/docker-config.yml:/etc/promtail/docker-config.yml
    command: -config.file=/etc/promtail/docker-config.yml
    networks:
      - kafka-net

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    container_name: grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - kafka-net
```

Everything worked fine. Then I wanted to deploy it with ansible through Jenkins to our dev environments. The environment is based on **Linux ubuntu**. Nothing special because the same flow is tested many times deploying our services. The deployment does not include docker-compose, it is just about individual podman containers.

The loki config looks like this:

```yaml
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
  grpc_listen_port: 9096

common:
  path_prefix: /tmp/loki
  storage:
    filesystem:
      chunks_directory: /tmp/loki/chunks
      rules_directory: /tmp/loki/rules
  replication_factor: 1
  ring:
    instance_addr: 127.0.0.1
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h

ruler:
  alertmanager_url: http://localhost:9093

analytics:
  reporting_enabled: false
```

The promtail looks like this:

```yaml
server:
  http_listen_address: 0.0.0.0
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
- job_name: varlogs
  static_configs:
    - targets: [localhost]
      labels:
        job: varlogs
        __path__: /var/logtest/system.log
- job_name: kafka
  kafka:
    brokers:
    - kafka_broker:29092
    topics:
    - grafana
    labels:
      job: kafka
      host: ${HOSTNAME:promtail}
  relabel_configs:
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
          - __meta_kafka_topic
        target_label: topic
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
          - __meta_kafka_partition
        target_label: partition
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
          - __meta_kafka_group_id
        target_label: group
```

I created podman bridge network called mycustom-bridge-net.

kafka-env.env file:

```
KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=yes
KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=broker,controller
KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=CLIENT://:29092,CONTROLLER://:9093,EXTERNAL://:9094
KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=CLIENT
KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=CLIENT://kafka_broker:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9094
KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=1@127.0.0.1:9093
KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=false
KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
```

The podman commands:

```yaml
podman run -d --env-file=/kafka/env/kafka-env.env -v /kafka/data:/bitnami/kafka --name kafka_broker --net=mycustom-bridge-net bitnami/kafka:latest

podman run -d -p 3100:3100 -v /grafana-loki/data:/loki -v /grafana-loki/config/local-config.yml:/etc/loki/local-config.yaml --name loki --net=mycustom-bridge-net grafana/loki:latest -config.file=/etc/loki/local-config.yaml

podman run -d -v /var/lib/containers:/var/lib/containers -v /grafana-promtail/config/docker-config.yml:/etc/promtail/docker-config.yml --name promtail --net=mycustom-bridge-net grafana/promtail:latest -config.file=/etc/promtail/docker-config.yml

podman run -d -p 3000:3000 -v /grafana/data:/var/lib/grafana --name grafana --net=mycustom-bridge-net grafana/grafana:latest
```

I have to say, if there is any mistake in these configuration files it is probably typo because I deployed every single service mentioned here. Communication between Kafka and Promtail is running well. I saw push into Loki from Promtail as well, BUT when I wanted to connect into Loki through grafana datasource I got this:

**Unable to fetch labels from Loki (Failed to call resource), please check the server logs for more details**

I tried to call Loki health check from browser http://IP_ADDRESS:3100/ready and I got **ready**. Every time when I tried to call from the browser the labels endpoint "/loki/api/v1/labels" it returns nothing mostly it timed out.

**EDIT**
BUT when I tried to call Loki's health check by curl:

curl http://localhost:3100/ready

from Kafka container, I get 503 - Service unavailable. I guess there is a wrong network setup between these containers within network mycustom-bridge-net.

CONCLUSION: Does anyone know why I cannot get the labels from Loki ?

Comment: `localhost` from the Kafka container refers to itself, not the Loki service, so I'm not sure I understand why you expected that to work, or why it would return any response since the Kafka service isn't http-based nor running anything on port 3100

Comment: @OneCricketeer sorry, for my bad explanation, I tried to call health check on localhost:3100/ready by curl from Kafka container. I mean I did not do it by Kafka itself. Do you understand?

Comment: Again, "curl from Kafka container" would refer to the Kafka container itself, which has nothing running on port 3100 that is an HTTP service. Perhaps you should try `curl http://loki:3100/ready` after a `docker-compose exec kafka_broker sh`?

Comment: any special logs from Loki?
And when you said `I saw push into Loki from Promtail as well`, how did you verify?
Also, what was your configuration of Loki datasource in grafana?